# Laravel - Eloquent merge collection with single item

Tags: laravel, collections, merge, eloquent

How do I merge an Eloquent collection with a single item? Trying to merge causes the error:

`Call to a member function getKey() on boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Collection's `push` method:

```
$collection = new Collection;
$collection->push($item);
```

Comment: I looked all over the place for this dumb question and finally found the answer so I added this to hopefully save some other people time.